# using hidden input types for multiple textareas, creating multiple inserts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've Built a CMS that allows the user to save pages with 'panels' which are basically divs containing their own content. It's using TinyMCE within the div to create content, and I've gotten it working but only with one main panel and I'm trying to figure out ways to modify this to save multiple panels.

My if statement grabs $value from the URL value and if it's 1 it uses the fullwidth html template

```
<?php if($value == 1){?>
    <?php $panelType = 1;?>
    <div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth" id="full">
        <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
            <form  id="form-data3" method="post">
              <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea3" name="fullText"></textarea>
              <input type="submit" value="Save Content">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I then have javascript that saves the content from the text area as the value of a hidden input in my 'Save Page' form that calls the mysql insert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function content() {
    var content = tinyMCE.get('mytextarea3').getContent();
    $("#new").val(content);
}
</script>

<form action="addPage.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="pageType" value="<?php echo $value;?>">//This comes from the url value
<input type="hidden" name="panelType" value="<?php echo $panelType;?>">//How would I loop this and the next hiddent input
<input type="hidden" id="new" name="page_content" value=""> //The javascript saves the textarea content as this value
<input class="form-control" id="addTitle" name="addTitle">
<input type="submit" name="Save Page">
```

My addpage.php script takes the form and inserts a record into the pages table, gets that insert ID, inserts a record to the content table, gets that ID and then lastly inserts into the panels table using the retrieved page and content IDs (this insert script is at the bottom). Up to this point it works flawlessly.

My problem is adding in multiple panel types. So let's say I modify my html template to now set panelType based on each DIV and have my javascript work on both textareas

```
<?php if($value == 1){?>

    <div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth" id="full">
        <?php $panelType = 1;?>
        <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
            <form  id="form-data3" method="post">
              <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea3" name="fullText">Some Text Here</textarea>
              <input type="submit" value="Save Content">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 halfWidth" id="half">
        <?php $panelType = 2;?>
        <div class="halfContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
            <form  id="form-data4" method="post">
              <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea4" name="halfText">Some Text There</textarea>
              <input type="submit" value="Save Content">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function content() {
    var content = tinyMCE.get('mytextarea3').getContent();
    $("#new").val(content);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function content() {
    var content = tinyMCE.get('mytextarea4').getContent();
    $("#new").val(content);
}
</script>
```

So this won't work because I'm trying to set both textarea content as the value for #new. But even if I had 2 hidden input fields it wouldn't insert into the database correctly. So I don't know if I would be able to loop this as a hidden type for my insert or if there's another way.

Based on my insert script, the records I would be expecting from above html template would be

```
pages

ID | Title    | page_type_id
1  | TitleNew | 1     /*this comes from $value*/

content

ID | Content
1  | Some Text Here
2  | Some Text There

panels

ID | panel_type_ID | page_id | content_id
1  |     1         |     1   |   1
2  |     2         |     1   |   2
```

This works for one insert in all 3 tables but if I can set multiple panel types to each div, how can I modify this to still insert the one page record but successfully account for multiple panel and content?

Here's the add page script

```
//Insert Page
$title = $_POST['addTitle'];
$page_type = $_POST['pageType'];


$addpage = "
INSERT INTO pages (title, page_type_id)
VALUES ('$title','$page_type');
";
$mysqlConn->query($addpage)

$page_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;

//Insert Content
$content = $_POST['page_content'];

$addContent = "
INSERT INTO content(content)
VALUES('$content');
";

$mysqlConn->query($addContent);

$cont_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;

//Insert panel(s)
$panelID = $_POST['panelType'];
$addPanel = "
INSERT INTO panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
VALUES ('$panelID', '$page_id', '$cont_id');
";
$mysqlConn->query($addPanel);
```

Comment: Seems overcomplicated vs using one form wrapping all the textareas and just sending what's in them. Or submitting each textarea form using ajax right away once user clicks "save content"

Comment: Note that defining the same function more than once overwrites any prior instance of that function

Comment: I don't use Ajax really, could you give me an example of doing that?

Comment: Can be as simple as `$('.my-form-class').on('submit', function(e){e.preventDefault(); $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(response){/* do something with response*/}); });` Note this disregards error handling but gives basic start point

Comment: So since I need the page record and content records in order to save panel records, would I need to save the textarea content with ajax and then when they do the final form to save the page, I would actually insert into mysql there?

Comment: Up to you how the process flow would go. Personally I don't see value in sending unedited data

Comment: incidentally, the php/sql code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Disregard..was thinking about editing existing content

Comment: Ah, no I still have to do that eventually in another function. Right now I'm just stuck on this part

Comment: @charlietfl I've been trying to make sense of this but I'm still stuck.... So if I want each div (that holds its own text area) to have a panel type and then on submit I want to save a record for the page and then each text areas content with record for that page, I still don't know how I would do that in one function

Comment: Why not wrap all the textareas in one form?

Comment: So then I would put a form around all divs with text areas, each div having its own hidden input and value for panel type? Then use JavaScript or Ajax to transfer those on submit along with the current form values?

Comment: @charlietfl if there's any way to give me an example with my actual template as an answer I'd gladly accept and up vote it. I'm still so lost on where to go from here